# How do I create a dispatch_queue with QoS attributes in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift3

I have code like this in Swift 2:

```
let attrs = dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class(DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL, QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)
let myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.serial-queue", attrs)
```

This doesn't compile in Swift 3, because `dispatch_queue_attr_make_with_qos_class` and `dispatch_queue_create` aren't available. How do I make a serial queue with a custom QoS class?

Comment: I appreciate that you take the time to document the issues you run into. I run into your material all the time

Comment: @AMomchilov I'm really glad that it's helpful :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueue) is now a `class`, and you can use its `init(label:attributes:target:)` initializer. The attributes are now an OptionSet called [`DispatchQueueAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/dispatchqueueattributes), which has instances `.serial` and `.qosUtility`.

Putting it together:

```
let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.serial-queue",
                            attributes: [.serial, .qosUtility])
```

Comment: In the last version that I tested of Swift 3 (which is XCode 8 Beta 6), this declaration gives the error message "Type 'DispatchQueue.Attributes' has no member 'serial'". Any idea on how to force it to be a serial queue?

Comment: Serial is the default.